# When creating envelope from template, is it possible to change the signer type from signer to in-person signer?

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating an envelope from template using the REST api. Recipient 2 on the template is signer type "signer". Is it possible to adjust this in the template roles portion of the JSON body so recipient 2 becomes an in-person signer?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do at the time of creating an envelope, but you can update envelope the envelope with below API call:

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients
```

For instance, create an envelope in `created (draft)` status,

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

{
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [{
                    "email": "signer1@1mail.com",
                    "name": "Signer1 Name",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Signer1"
                },
                {
                    "recipientId": "2",
                    "email": "hostEmail@email.com",
                    "name": "Host Name",
                    "roleName": "Signer2"
                }]
            },
            "sequence": "1"
        }],
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "267c3673-3381-4b3d-9040-706b341c721g"
        }]
    }],
    "status": "created"
}
```

then call [EnvelopeRecipients: update](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/) to update the recipientId2 to Inperson Signer.

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients

{
    "inPersonSigners": [{
        "roleName": "Signer2",
        "routingOrder": 1,
        "hostEmail": "hostemail@email.com",
        "hostName": "Host Name",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "signerName": "Signer Name"
    }]
}
```